# EF Core, code-first, SQL Server, Blazor application: how to properly initialize the database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

My application have to create database and import data, this is done once the app is deployed.

I noticed that the database could be only created if my connection string specifies user `sa`, or other user with `CREATE DATABASE` privilege on `master` database. Well, the first time I created the database manually, then created a user for it, then used EF (via Package Manager Console) to create the structure.

Then I accidentally deleted the database, so I tried to recreate it with EF which failed with "create database failed" and that I need "create database" privilege on "master".

So I thought, well, I'll give it a try, I specify `sa` as the user. And no initial catalog, let EF Core create the database, right?

Here comes the surprise: it didn't create any databases, it created tables in my `master` database. This is definitely not what I wanted! How to specify the name of the database to use?

I know this question was asked before, with the answer "use the connection string name". NO - IT DOESN'T WORK in Blazor application with Identity. My connection has a name that is NOT USED, the database is not created, my tables goes to `master`. In this framework, the configuration sits in `appsettings.json` file. There is a special method to fetch connection strings, but their names are not special. It's just a configuration key as any other and I don't think its name is used for anything but finding the appropriate string in the file.

If I create the database manually, then create user, then grant privileges, then set the connection string to that user, with initial catalog set to my database - then it works, but there are several problems here. I try to do as much as possible within my application, I try to avoid manual actions as much as I can. I need the deployment process as simple as possible. First run on special privileges, to import data, second run on regular user privileges.

Then I'd like to make limit the concrete RDBMS dependence to the minimum. Let EF Core do everything it can automagically.

Is it even possible?

What is the best common practice?

Do you create databases and privileges manually, or can it be automated in EF?
How does EF create the database? Does it set any special options like default collation? What options should I set when creating the database manually?

Comment: Can you clarify how your configuration passes the connection information to your DbContext?  Perhaps the solution here: https://www.benday.com/2017/02/17/ef-core-migrations-without-hard-coding-a-connection-string-using-idbcontextfactory/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft : YES! It works.